# Wolfe Conditions and capturing the minimizer

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Hi guys I am learning about line search algorithms. In general the idea is that we want to solve the minimization problem

$$\min_\alpha f(x_k+ \alpha p_k)$$

Then we use alpha as our step-size. In practice this is expensive to solve so we get a close enough alpha not nessesary the best. One of the most used conditions to ensure we do decrease the fuchtion are the Wolfe conditions

$$f(\mathbf{x}_k+\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k)\leq f(\mathbf{x}_k)+c_1\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$$
and 
$$-\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k+\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k) \leq -c_2\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$$

My question is are we guaranteed that among the alphas that the Wolfe conditions we have the actual solution to the minimization problem? To me there is not an obvious answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been posted more than a year ago, but if someone else is having a similar question:

In general, we want to solve the minimization problem (for $x$, not $\alpha$!)
$$\min_\mathbf{x} f(\mathbf{x})$$

and since we are going to iteratively wander around the space searching for the minimum, it would be nice to, at each step $k$, choose reasonable search direction $\mathbf{p_k}$ and step size $\alpha$. Assuming we have a reasonable $\mathbf{p_k}$ we now need to select $\alpha$ such that:
$$\min_\alpha f(\mathbf{x_k}+ \alpha \mathbf{p_k})$$

> *My question is are we guaranteed that among the alphas that [meet] the Wolfe conditions we have the actual solution to the minimization problem?*

No, selecting $\alpha$ that meets Wolfe conditions will only ensure that (assuming the angle $\theta_k$ between $\mathbf{p}_k$ and $\nabla f(\mathbf{x_k})$ is greater than zero) gradient with each steps converges to zero, i.e.

$$\nabla f(\mathbf{x_k}) \to 0$$

This is because the first condition, i.e.

$$f(\mathbf{x}_k+\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k)\leq f(\mathbf{x}_k)+c_1\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$$

makes sure that at the new point $\mathbf{x}_k+\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k$ you decreased $f$ "sufficiently" and the second condition, i.e.

$$-\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k+\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k) \leq -c_2\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$$

or (after negating both sides):

$$\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k+\alpha_k\mathbf{p}_k) \geq c_2\mathbf{p}_k^{\mathrm T}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$$

makes sure that the slope at the new point is bigger, or "less negative" (note that direction search $\mathbf{p_k}$ points in the opposite direction than the gradient, i.e. $\mathbf{p_k}^T\nabla f(\mathbf{x_k}) < 0$), and that's exactly what we want to achieve - local minimum of $f$ will be found where the gradient is zero (unless its a saddle point).

TLDR: $\alpha$ that meets Wolfe conditions will not give you *the actual solution to the minimization problem* but will make sure (together with the assumption about non-zero angle $\theta_k$ between $\mathbf{p}_k$ and $\nabla f(\mathbf{x_k})$) that at each step you'll be closer to the point where the gradient is zero.

Comment: Very nice answer! If I may ask: You say that the second Wolfe condition makes sure that the sloped is getting less negative, and that's what we want. I can see that's one way of looking at it; but on the other hand, don't we want (at least for the first iterations) to find points where the slope is $more$ and $more$ negative, so that we reach a minimum faster?

Comment: Also, if I may clarify something; you say that selecting an $\alpha$ which satisfies the Wolfe conditions ensures that $\nabla f(x_k) \to 0.$ Is the formal theorem here like this? Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{something}$ function, and suppose that there exists at least one point where the gradient of $f$ is zero. For any $x_0$, if we always pick a descent direction $p_k$ and a step length $\alpha$ satisfying the Wolfe conditions, then $x_k$ will converge to a point where the gradient is zero.